# Angular Material 2 Drag Drops should each other not be overlapped

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag, angular-cdk

I do implement now a web application with angular material. 
now I have a problem by implementing drag and drop.

the code as follows:

```html
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
  Drag me around 1
</div>

<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
  Drag me around 2
</div>
```

The problem is, I wannt this 2 drag drops do not be overlapped. [image]

I dont wannt like this:

[image]

this would be perfect, if the box 2 is over box 1, the box 1 will be moved to somewhere automatically.

any one some suggestion or solution.